# SQL query counting unique identifiers vs how many in second column match each

Tags: sql, count, inner-join, aggregate-functions

[image]

As seen in the picture, my current query displays the EmployeeID and then in the right column the visitor associated with that EmployeeID. I think what I need here is a select distinct count.

How its displayed.

```
Id                  EmployeeId          IsActive
45869625-6e26-4a3e- 45869625-6e26-4a3e- Y
c67c29c6-1c52-42bf- c67c29c6-1c52-42bf- Y
1b255e77-3532-4c6f- 1b255e77-3532-4c6f- Y
1b255e77-3532-4c6f- 1b255e77-3532-4c6f- Y
```

How I would like it to be queried. I basically want to remove all of the duplicate employees and show how many visitors per unique employee identifier.

```
Id                  numofvisitors
45869625-6e26-4a3e  1
c67c29c6-1c52-42bf  1
1b255e77-3532-4c6f  2
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
select e.id, count(*) as num_of_visitors
from dbo.employee e
inner join dbo.visitor on e.id = v.employeeid
where e.isactive = 'Y'
group by e.id
```